# Difference between `height:'100%', width: '100%'` vs. `Flex:1`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Wondering what the differences between the two are, it was my assumption flex:1 expanded fully in both directions. But in a react-native app, if I have an `<ImageBackground>` with style of `height:'100%', width: '100%'` the child buttons are only as big as their inner text requires. but if the image background style is `flex:1` the *child* buttons expand to full screen width.

here's is button styling:

```
btn: {
    paddingTop: "10rem",
    paddingBottom: "7rem",
    paddingHorizontal: "15rem",
    marginTop: "15rem",
    marginHorizontal: "20rem",
    backgroundColor: "#333",
    "@media ios": {
      borderRadius: 50
    },
    "@media android": {
      borderRadius: 50,
      elevation: 4
    },
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 0
  },
  btn_text: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: "20rem",
    fontFamily: "BungeeInline-Regular",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
```

Details on the effect the container is having on its children in both scenarios?

Comment: Here is how I understand it : In flex:1 - the container can specify a consistent layout of its children hence in your case ; the child button expanded to full screen width.

In height, width :100 ? % - I understand that these dimensions should be unitless. why are you giving units? [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html] and regarding the container effect - I am not sure. I would like find out too.

Comment: the width/height in this context is unites (ie `'100%'`), in the snippets, the `#rem` is a 'unit' based off a normalize function

Answer (score 2):

Flex one has a few traits:

- It needs an explicit dimension set in one of its parents.
- It needs its direct parent to have `display: flex`.
- It will fit the parent's dimension, but will be affected by the parent's padding.
- It will be affected by sibling elements.

Assuming you have two `flex: 1` sibling elements, then they will fill equal ratio inside the parent element (1/2 and 1/2). If it's a `flex: 1` & `flex: 2`, then they will take up 1/3 and 2/3 of the space. If you have an element with explicit height and width as a sibling, then `flex: 1` will fill up-to that sibling.

Comment: in this scenario, the parent has `flex:1`, not the children. the children (buttons) dont have height/width explicitly defined. so if parent (`<ImageBackground>`) is set to `flex:1`, does it enforce some rule on its children, the sibling buttons, and if so what is it? something like @Lelo suggested?

Comment: If `ImageBackground` has `flex: 1`, then its parent needs to have `display: flex`. `flex: 1` shouldn't be doing anything if a `display: flex` is not declared for its parent.